# Unable to upload large files to sonatype nexus 2 repo via browser

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus2

I am trying to upload a fie of 10gig to my releases repository in nexus 2. I am doing it via browser/GUI(tried on chrome, IE, mozilla), and every time i try it hungs or timeout and the upload fails. I am not sure why.
Yes i am aware there are other ways to do better and easier, but i still need to figure out why uploading via browser  fails. Any one has an idea ??

Comment: Any error in the nexus.log?  Do you see the request in the request.log?  If so what's the status code by it.  Do you have a reverse proxy or load balancer in between whose logs you can check to make sure the traffic is uninterrupted?

Comment: @joedragons I didnt get much info in the nexus.log/request.log.
Yes i do have a reverse proxy, for now the upload has been successful but i think that this is something to do with my reverse proxy.
I will try to enable it again and do another major upload then i would find something on my proxy logs. 
For now i would say it as resolved

Comment: If you're using nginx, be sure to set client_max_body_size to a reasonable value. The default is tiny:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size